# Aws step function deployment log access issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am running into Some permissions issue i am not able to figure out.

The step function deployment fails because of error:

```
Error: AccessDeniedException: The state machine IAM Role is not authorized to access the Log Destination
10:12:19    status code: 400, request id: ff46f8c0-fcc8-4190-ba6a-13f5ab617c78
10:12:19  
10:12:19    on step_function.tf line 1, in resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "oss_integration_data_process_sf":
10:12:19     1: resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "os_int_data_process_sf" {
```

funny thing is, it only happens to one lambda while all lambdas have same prefix and we have step function give permissions as:

````
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:AssociateKmsKey",
                "logs:CreateLogDelivery",
                "logs:GetLogDelivery",
                "logs:UpdateLogDelivery",
                "logs:DeleteLogDelivery",
                "logs:ListLogDeliveries",
                "logs:PutResourcePolicy",
                "logs:DescribeResourcePolicies",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:XXXX:log-group:*/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }```

I can run the lambda after deployment and see CW log stream with lambda name is getting created.
````

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and resolved by updating policies for the Role as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-logs.html

Normally PutLogEvents, CreateLogStream should be enough for resources like Lambda but apprantly Step Function need other log policies as well.

Comment: Thanks. It was simply a case of creating a new Policy and pasting the example code from that documentation page. Once I'd attached the Policy to the Role associated with the Step Function then it all worked (finally!)

Comment: This was my issue as well.  I believe what was missing from the usual put and create was "logs:DescribeLogGroups"

Answer (score 5):

You can create the permissions using a wildcard `*`  in the resources and  your permission issue will be solved, as the documentation [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-logs.html) suggests.

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogDelivery",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:GetLogDelivery",
                    "logs:UpdateLogDelivery",
                    "logs:DeleteLogDelivery",
                    "logs:ListLogDeliveries",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents",
                    "logs:PutResourcePolicy",
                    "logs:DescribeResourcePolicies",
                    "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

If want to follow the Least privilege access principle, there are some points about the CloudWatch permissions that you need to check:

- The `LogDelivery` and `ResourcePolicy` actions don’t support Resource types, so they must use a  wildcard `*` on the Resources.

```yaml
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'logs:CreateLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:GetLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:UpdateLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:DeleteLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:ListLogDeliveries'
            - 'logs:PutResourcePolicy'
            - 'logs:DescribeResourcePolicies'
          Resource: '*'
```

- The `PutLogEvents` action are in the [`log-stream*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-log-stream) level so if want to restrict, you need to follow something like this:

```yaml
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:${Region}:${Account}:log-group:${LogGroupName}:log-stream:${LogStreamName}
```

- The `Destination` related actions are in the  [`destination*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-destination) level, so if want to restrict, you need to follow something like this:

```yaml
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'logs:PutDestination'
            - 'logs:PutDestinationPolicy'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:${Region}:${Account}:log-group:${LogGroupName}:destination:${DestinationName}'
```

- The `PutSubscriptionFilter` action are in the [`log-group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-log-group) and [`destination*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-destination) levels.

More information about the CloudWatch Logs action and permissions can be found here:

[Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html)

Comment: `logs:PutDestination` was what I was missing, was not present in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error `The state machine IAM Role is not authorized to access the Log Destination` when using a cloudformation template, but the actual problem was that the YAML field `CloudWatchLogsLogGroup` was misconfigured.

So I updated it to use the syntax below and it all worked.

```yaml
  StateMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    DependsOn: 
      - LogGroup
      - CustomRole
    Properties:
      Name: StateMachine
      Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/CustomRole
      Logging:
        Destinations:
          - CloudWatchLogsLogGroup: 
              LogGroupArn: !GetAtt LogGroup.Arn          
        IncludeExecutionData: true
        Level: ALL
```

Nonetheless, I think the AWS documentation is very confusing on this topic.

Comment: In AWS docs they state the ARN should end with "*". Apparently this is not so.

Comment: Be sure to include the IncludeExecutionData: true attribute, or you will continue to get permissions errors that don't point to this issue!