# The state machine IAM Role is not authorized to access the Log Destination

Tags: aws-cloudformation, devops, amazon-iam

I am trying to deploy a CF stack which is failing because of an IAM permission issue. The concerning resources in the stack for this issue are:

1. state machine (step function)
2. Cloudwatch log group
3. A subscription filter for the log group

This subscription filter forwards the logs to Kenesis where the logs are streamed into splunk. Coming back to my issue, when I try to deploy the above CF stack, I get the following error: `The state machine IAM Role is not authorized to access the Log Destination`

I have given the following permissions to the role attached to the state machine

```js
StateMachineRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    RoleName: StateMachineRole-${self:custom.env.stage}
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: states.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole

  LambdaPolicy:
   Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
   DeletionPolicy: Retain
   DependsOn: CustomLogGroup
   Properties:
     PolicyName: LambdaPolicy-${self:custom.env.stage}
     PolicyDocument:
       Version: '2012-10-17'
       Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
          Resource: lambdaArn
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'logs:CreateLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:GetLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:UpdateLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:DeleteLogDelivery'
            - 'logs:ListLogDeliveries'
            - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
            - 'logs:PutResourcePolicy'
            - 'logs:DescribeResourcePolicies'
            - 'logs:DescribeLogGroups'
            - 'logs:PutDestination'
            - 'logs:PutSubscriptionFilter'
            - 'logs:PutDestinationPolicy'
          Resource: !GetAtt CustomLogGroup.Arn
  
  
  /*CustomLogGroup*/
  CustomLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      KmsKeyId: !ImportValue XXXXXXX
      LogGroupName: CustomLogGroupName
      RetentionInDays:  ${file(./.env.${self:custom.env.stage}.yaml):cloudwatchLogs.retentionDays
```

Referred to the following SO question: [Aws step function deployment log access issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71956893/aws-step-function-deployment-log-access-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the actions don’t support Resource types, so using a wildcard `*` will solve your permission issue.

```
Resource: '*'
```

If want to follow the Least privilege access principle, there are some points about the CloudWatch permissions that you need to check:

- The `LogDelivery` and `ResourcePolicy` actions don’t support Resource types, so they must use a  wildcard `*` on the Resources.

  ```
   - Effect: Allow
     Action:
       - 'logs:CreateLogDelivery'
       - 'logs:GetLogDelivery'
       - 'logs:UpdateLogDelivery'
       - 'logs:DeleteLogDelivery'
       - 'logs:ListLogDeliveries'
       - 'logs:PutResourcePolicy'
       - 'logs:DescribeResourcePolicies'
     Resource: '*'
  ```
- The `PutLogEvents` action are in the [`log-stream*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-log-stream) level so if want to restrict, you need to follow something like this:

  ```
   - Effect: Allow
     Action:
       - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
     Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:${Region}:${Account}:log-group:${LogGroupName}:log-stream:${LogStreamName}
  ```
- The `Destination` related actions are in the  [`destination*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-destination) level, so if want to restrict, you need to follow something like this:

  ```
   - Effect: Allow
     Action:
       - 'logs:PutDestination'
       - 'logs:PutDestinationPolicy'
     Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:${Region}:${Account}:log-group:${LogGroupName}:destination:${DestinationName}'
  ```
- The `PutSubscriptionFilter` action are in the [`log-group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-log-group) and [`destination*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html#amazoncloudwatchlogs-destination) levels.

More information about the CloudWatch Logs action and permissions can be found here:

[Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatchlogs.html)